# Cartesian Product in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there any easy way to do cartesian product in Tensorflow like itertools.product? I want to get combination of elements of two tensors (`a` and `b`), in Python it is possible via itertools as `list(product(a, b))`. I am looking for an alternative in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that both `a` and `b` are 1-D tensors.

To get the cartesian product of the two, I would use a combination of `tf.expand_dims` and `tf.tile`:

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3]) 
b = tf.constant([4,5,6,7]) 

tile_a = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), [1, tf.shape(b)[0]])  
tile_a = tf.expand_dims(tile_a, 2) 
tile_b = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, 0), [tf.shape(a)[0], 1]) 
tile_b = tf.expand_dims(tile_b, 2) 

cartesian_product = tf.concat([tile_a, tile_b], axis=2) 

cart = tf.Session().run(cartesian_product) 

print(cart.shape) 
print(cart)
```

You end up with a len(a) * len(b) * 2 tensor where each combination of the elements of `a` and `b` is represented in the last dimension.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter solution to the same, using [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) for broadcasting (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1,2,3]) 
b = tf.constant([4,5,6,7]) 

a, b = a[ None, :, None ], b[ :, None, None ]
cartesian_product = tf.concat( [ a + tf.zeros_like( b ),
                                 tf.zeros_like( a ) + b ], axis = 2 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( cartesian_product ) )
```

will output:

> [[[1 4]
>     [2 4]
>     [3 4]]
>
> [[1 5]
>     [2 5]
>     [3 5]]
>
> [[1 6]
>     [2 6]
>     [3 6]]
>
> [[1 7]
>     [2 7]
>     [3 7]]]

Comment: This answer is awesome! While maybe less readable it is more generalizable. Seems to work for tensors of arbitrary dimensions after dimension 1. For example it still gives back what you expect for 
`a = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]])`
`b = tf.constant([[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])`

Answer (score 4):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
b = tf.constant([2, 3])
c = tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(a, b, indexing='ij'), axis=-1)
c = tf.reshape(c, (-1, 2))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Output:

```
[[0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]]
```

credit to jdehesa: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123763/in-tensorflow-how-to-cross-stack-two-tensor)

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct version of Sunreef's answer uses `tf.stack` instead of `tf.concat`

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3]) 
b = tf.constant([4,5,6,7]) 

tile_a = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), [1, tf.shape(b)[0]]) 
tile_b = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, 0), [tf.shape(a)[0], 1])  
ans = tf.stack([tile_a, tile_b], -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inspired by Jaba's answer. If you want to get the cartesian_product of two 2-D tensors, you can do it as following:

input a:[N,L] and b:[M,L], get a [N*M,L] concat tensor

```
tile_a = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), [1, M, 1])  
tile_b = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, 0), [N, 1, 1]) 

cartesian_product = tf.concat([tile_a, tile_b], axis=2)   
cartesian = tf.reshape(cartesian_product, [N*M, -1])

cart = tf.Session().run(cartesian) 

print(cart.shape)
print(cart)
```

Comment: this doesn't work if a or b are empty, but you can fix it by using `a.shape[-1] + b.shape[-1]` instead of -1 in `[N * M, -1]`