# Taking all combinations of records from two TFRecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have two TFRecords `A` and `B` of different sizes and containing different data elements.

I need to take all possible pairs of records from `A` and `B`. Therefore, during training or testing, I would like the signal of epoch to end only when all combinations have been exhausted, after which the process should resume for the next epoch.

In doing this, of course, I would like to specify a `batchsize`.

I have gone through the documentation of `tf.data.Dataset` and have found nothing which does something like this.

Of course, if I were to write a python generator, this could be accomplished. But unfortunately, this is not useful because according to documentation, python generators will be bounded by the `GIL` i.e the `global interpreter lock`.

Thus, suppose that,

`A` contains `{image1, image2, image3}`, while `B` contains `{im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6}`. And I have specified a batchsize of `2`. Then I would like the output to be something like following :

`(image1, im1) and (image2, im4)`

`(image3, im2) and (image1, im2)`

`(image2, im1) and (image2, im3)`

`..............`

`15 more combinations`

and then the next epoch starts.

How can that be achieved in TensorFlow ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some SO posts about how to compute the cartesian product of two arrays using [Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684492/numpy-equivalent-of-itertools-product) or [Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132665/cartesian-product-in-tensorflow).

If your arrays are two big for an in-memory computation, your best bet is probably to use two `tf.data.Dataset` (on for each array) and make a double loop:

```py
for a in dataset_A:
  for b in dataset_B.batch(2):
     batch = [[a, b[0]], [a, b[1]] # Or something similar (it should have a TF function to do it)
```

Using [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function), looping over a Dataset is known to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function where generator function will implement your logic, e.g. cross product of two other datasets. To randomly draw a pair of sample from zipped dataset `db1` and `db2`, i shuffled each dataset independently.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [5, 6, 7, 8]

db1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(A).shuffle(len(A)).repeat()
db2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(B).shuffle(len(B)).repeat()

def cross_db_generator():
    for db1_example, db2_example in zip(db1, db2):
        print(db1_example.numpy(), db2_example.numpy())
        yield db1_example, db2_example


cross_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(cross_db_generator, output_types=(tf.uint8, tf.uint8))
cross_db = cross_db.batch(2)

for sample in cross_db:
    print((sample[0][0].numpy(), sample[1][0].numpy()), (sample[0][1].numpy(), sample[1][1].numpy()))
```

Comment: using `from_generator` will not be efficient because it is bound by Python's GIL right ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't investigated on the efficiency of `from_generator`. You may want to check out this question on:[parallelizing tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086599).